What's the proper moderation action for answers that are little more than a recommendation of a ChatGPT prompt?
I recently encountered this answer:

0
For Android 12 and above... and this is going to sound a little funny.... try chatGPT for the answer you're looking for.
Here's the prompt I used
show me how to add Bluetooth permissions to mainactivity in Android studio using java and minSdkVersion 29
New times for us all programmers !!

This seems quite similar to a link-only answer (as it's dependent on ChatGPT not changing its behavior), not to mention a borderline violation of the ban on ChatGPT plagiarism answers.
What is the proper moderation action for this type of answer?

For the record, this specific answer is a triplicate. Protip: if an answer starts with a random number, it's often because it was copy/pasted from somewhere and that number is the score of where it was copied from.

@VLAZ Yes, I did actually encounter all three in the VLQ queue (where I voted to delete as NAA). I'm not sure if that was the right thing or not though.

Normally I would say it's not an answer and so should be deleted, but unfortunately "ask ChatGPT" is technically an answer to the rather vaguely-worded question "what can I do to solve this problem"... just a rather poor one. I've downvoted it, but not sure it warrants outright deletion.

This is probably analogous to an answer providing only search keywords for your favorite search engine. I don't think that's considered a valid answer.

I wonder if we should update the answers to "correct" the 0 to a -6./sarcasm

“What is the proper moderation action for this type of answer?” - Downvote the answer since suggesting ChatGPT isn’t helpful to the community. Vague questions should be closed not answered

Sadly, we don't have a "Kill it with fire!" button.

@PM2Ring For regular users, that button is labeled "Flag". For mods, well, I'm bound to secrecy...

This is not an answer
It is indistinguishable from your answer is in another castle. It could have also been "You can find the answer if you go to the library and get a book". It is similarly useless at actually resolving the question at hand.
The litmus test is "if I cannot leave the site, can this help me at all". An answer like "Use foo " can help by suggesting foo. It might not be a good or a complete answer but it has value that exists without visiting the link.
There is no distinguishable difference between hiding the whole answer behind a link or hiding it behind "use ChatGPT".
We do not even have to discuss how asking a gen AI tool is not even guaranteed to provide you with a correct answer. Because for SO it is not an answer.

"There is no distinguishable difference…" There is, actually. Hiding the whole answer behind a link makes it NAA per SO rules, but the answer quite likely does exist behind that link. This is not true with "use ChatGPT", because ChatGPT is not going to provide a correct, usable answer to the question (it's a text generator). So, at best, "use ChatGPT" is more akin to saying "figure it out yourself"—it doesn't help at all. I'd say this is rude/abusive, not NAA. But I suppose whether that flag would be sustained depends on the exact wording. Either way, it needs to be deleted urgently.
